# Lapply with ifelse condition

Tags: r, if-statement, dataframe, sapply

I've a dataframe which contains 40 rows and 10 columns. I want to derive a column if index of rows less than 17, new column is called Prediction equals to 'Value' column. What I mean is that:

```
ID  Year    Value
1   2016    114235
2   2016    114235
3   2016    114235
4   2016    114235
5   2016    114235
```

Then:

```
ID  Year    Value   Prediction
1   2016    114235  114235
2   2016    114235  114235
3   2016    114235  114235
4   2016    114235  114235
5   2016    114235  114235
```

I tried to code as follows and all rowns of new column was 'NA'.

```
newdata$Prediction <- ifelse(nrow(newdata) <= 17, newdata$Value, NA)

newdata$Prediction <- lapply(newdata, function(x) ifelse(nrow(newdata) <= 17, newdata$Value, NA))
```

It doesn't work. How can I do that?

Comment: `df$Prediction <- NA; df$Prediction[1:17] <- df$Value[1:17]` ?

Answer (score 2):

Do you need the lapply function?

You could just do something like this:

```
nrow = 20
newdata <- data.frame(ID = 1:nrow,
           Year = rep(2016, nrow),
           Value = rep(114235, nrow))


newdata$Prediction <- newdata$Value
if (nrow(newdata) > 17) {
  newdata[17:nrow(newdata),]$Prediction <- NA
}

newdata
```

Like this, it wont change the data if less than 17 rows are at hand. Otherwise it would add new rows and fill them with NA.

Comment: What happens if `newdata` has less than 17 rows?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using

```
newdata$Prediction <- ifelse(nrow(newdata) <= 17, newdata$Value, NA)
```

you can use something like

```
newdata$Prediction <- ifelse(as.numeric(rownames(newdata)) <= 17, newdata$Value, NA)
```

The difference here is in understanding how `nrow()` and `rownames()` work.

for e.g., taking a threshold of `3` ,  your sample input returns

```
  ID Year  Value Prediction
1  1 2016 114235     114235
2  2 2016 114235     114235
3  3 2016 114235     114235
4  4 2016 114235         NA
5  5 2016 114235         NA
```

---

While the methods mentioned in the comments to your question are perfectly valid, I still post this because your attempt wasn't too far off.

---

Alternatively, you could also try using `tidyverse` functions:

```
newdata %>%
  mutate(rn = 1:n()) %>%
  mutate(Prediction = if_else(rn <= 3, Value, NULL)) %>%
  select(-rn)
```

Comment: This will produce NA for all Prediction rows, if the dataset has more than 17 rows.

Comment: @SeGa oops! Thanks for pointing that out. Fixed it now, and added a sample output as well

Answer (score 2):

I think that you can just change one small thing in your code to get what you want.

```
newdata$Prediction <- ifelse(newdata$ID <= 17, newdata$Value, NA)
```

You already have an ID column that appears to be sorted and thus is acting like the row number. nrow() will just give you the number of rows, and in your case the number of rows for your dataset is greater than 17 so you get NAs on every row.